# Copied android db file is empty

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to copy an android db file from my application folder to another one on SD card. And from DDMS file explorer i can notice that the copied file size is 0. This is my code bellow.

```
public boolean copyDBFile(){
    File dbFile =new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + DB_PATH);
    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
      + "/BACKUP_DIR");
    if (!exportDir.exists()) {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(exportDir, dbFile.getName());
    try {
        file.createNewFile();           
        copyFile(dbFile, file);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {     
        return false;
    }
}


public void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();

    try {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    } finally {
        if (inChannel != null)
          inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
          outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

Is it a permission issue? Thanks for help.

Comment: You should *always* have a catch statement for every try statement, otherwise you can't say if an exception happens. Here, add a catch to your try in copyFile.

Comment: can u explain that more plz? i think he does not want to catch the exception but simply close the channels to avoid leakage. do you mean that it is automatically caught? if yes then i think you have solved the problem :)

Comment: The db file isn't copied. Just a 0 size file with the same name. Seems like file is created but never copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@piyush 
Thanks for the try/catch notice. I found the error after adding a log trace in `boolean copyDBFile()` method at catch block.

```
public boolean copyDBFile(){
File dbFile =new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + DB_PATH);
File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
  + "/BACKUP_DIR");
if (!exportDir.exists()) {
    exportDir.mkdirs();
}

File file = new File(exportDir, dbFile.getName());
try {
    file.createNewFile();           
    copyFile(dbFile, file);
    return true;
} catch (IOException e) {  
    Log.e("Sarelo", "Error creating file", e);
    return false;
}
```

}

My `DB_PATH` was already set to  `/data/data/package/databases/data.db` and added to `Environment.getDataDirectory()` the `dbFile` result to `/data/data/data/package/databases/data.db`
That's the big mistake!  Thanks all for help :)

Comment: aaargh! :) your welcome and please vote up the answer and comments plz :)

Answer (score 0):

try using `outChannel.force(true);` before using the `transferTo(...);`

Comment: did you try adding a catch block and throwing an exception in it? just try to see if there is an exception that is being thrown but not shown because of the catch block absence.

Comment: Thanks for the try/catch notice. I found the error after adding a log trace